Facebook mobile federated sign-in not working
We've integrated Facebook Federated Sign-in along with AWS Cognito on our Application, the application is developed using Flutter for us to be able to used of its cross platform development, the sign-in works fine in Web Browsers and Mobile web browser but when it comes to our Mobile application it seems to have a problem. I've already checked all the configurations in facebook developer and everything was set perfectly since the web browser is perfectly fine. I can't seem to see where the problem is coming from. I've attached the screenshot of the error in this post.

